# Shifting page selection in bootstrap pagination

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Look here please:
https://embed.plnkr.co/M2XIlr/

Is it possible to reach following effect:

In case of many pages (such that it is this number is too big to diplay all pages):
Is it possible to shift in left and right to see next (and previous) pages?
I mean something like slider, so we can see (and click) `100-th` page without changing page (and being currently on first page).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. There are many free jquery plugins for this. I prefer DataTables for Bootstrap.

https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html